# Is the coefficient uniquely determined by the sign function?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming

Suppose $a\in R^p$, $b\in R^p$, and $||a||=||b||=1$, is it true that if $sign(a'x)=sign(b'x)$ for any $x\in R^p$, then $a=b$, where $sign(t)=1$ if $t\geq 0$ and $sign(t)=-1$ if $t<0$?

Comment: What does ' mean in this context? The dot-product?